# How to create S3 Bucket for three different environments using single root account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've one AWS root account, if I need to grant the S3 bucket access to our application resides in Dev, Test and Prod environments. These S3 bucket will be accessed only by application and not by individual / manual user. I can refer multiple approaches, not sure which one is best approach here? Could you pls suggest on this?

Option-1: Create IAM user account for each environment with programmatic access only. Provide the Access KeyId and Secret Access key to respective environment(Dev, Test and Prod) to access the S3 resource. Separate S3 bucket will be created for each environment, S3 bucket policy will only allow the access to specific IAM user account only.

Option-2: Three separate AWS accounts. Not sure how to proceed on this further, will be having three root accounts to manage and separate billing, one S3 bucket for each AWS account.

Option-3: I can refer the landing zone concepts that comes with AWS organization account, Shared Services account, Log Archive Account and Security Account. Not sure where to specify / create the resources and IAM user account.

Comment: I would typically recommend isolating env into their own account through organizations. You should generally never use static access keys (SSO for users, roles for services).

Comment: Thanks Jordanm, will check the roles for service approach.